# How can I make vertical fieldset scroll show up

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a `fieldset` inside a `div` that has `div` inside it, but as the content of `div` grows it overflows outside of `fieldset`, the scrollbar on `fieldset` shows up and works in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```css
.outerdiv-class {
  max-height: 94%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 240px;
}

.fieldset-class {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}

.innerdiv-class {
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv-class">
  <fieldset class="fieldset-class">
    <div class="innerdiv-class">
      ///content is KendoTreeview that overflows outside from fieldset in 
         chrome
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I don't want to give `div` a fixed height I want it to inherit from `fieldset` and outer `div` height to be responsive to window size.

Comment: You should clarify , also update the snippet with your code that demonstrate your issue. basicly it seems to work : https://jsfiddle.net/x3r4y1vt/ So where did you go wrong that you did not tell ? :)

Comment: Try adding an `overflow` rule on `.outer-div` or a `height` in `.fieldset-class`

Comment: @Ant Adding `overflow` rule on `.outerdiv-calss` didnt work but setting height on `fieldset-class` worked, was hoping to find a way to not set a fixed height, thanks for you answer anyways.

Comment: Does it work with a height of `auto`?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it does work in the link you provided the only difference is my content is not text inside div its Kendo-treeview.

Comment: @Ant it does not :(

Comment: I guess the reason why auto doesn't work and the reason why you have an issue to begin with is because of your tree view. Probably it's height for whatever reason is not factored into the DOM. You may want to add another wrapper to that and have the parent be `position:relative` (between `.fieldset-class` and `.inner-div`), but even that might not work